# effective way to build a string

Tags: ocaml

I want to build a long string dynamically and then write it to a file.
i have a code similar to:

```
let str = ref ""

let appnd s =
        str := (!str ^ (Printf.sprintf "%s\n" s))
```

But in runtime it works very slow. i think this approach is not efficient. What is the best way to build a long string?

building string and then writing to file is better or appending string directly to file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you append to a string, you have to copy it. If you imagine appending n pieces, you end up making roughly n*n copies of them. This is slow if n is big.

You're also choosing a slow way to append. It would be faster to say:

```
let append s = str := !str ^ s ^ "\n"
```

It might be better to use Buffer instead of String. If you have an idea of the final size of your string you can pre-allocate a buffer of the right size. It also wraps up the mutable state a little more nicely.

**Update**

Here's some simple code using Buffer:

```
let buf = Buffer.create 1024

let append s =
    Buffer.add_string buf s;
    Buffer.add_char buf '\n'

let getstring () =
    Buffer.contents buf
```

Here's a session:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# #use "b.ml";;
val buf : Buffer.t = <abstr>
val append : string -> unit = <fun>
val getstring : unit -> string = <fun>
# append "abc";;
- : unit = ()
# append "def";;
- : unit = ()
# getstring ();;
- : string = "abc\ndef\n"
```

For what it's worth I would try to write more functionally than this. I.e., I would pass the buffer around to the functions that want to use it rather than making `buf` a global variable.

Comment: thanks for suggesting Buffer. where i can find examples for working with Buffer?

Comment: The last time I checked, the compiler did something comparatively stupid for `!str ^ s ^ "\n"`. In the case of an arbitrarily large number of strings to catenate, my bet would be on `Printf.sprintf "%s%s%s…"`.

Comment: That's pretty unexpected. Thanks for the info. (Note to OP: I added example buffer code.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.concat` function or data structure from `Buffer` module.

About last question I'm not sure. It depends, I think.

Comment: thanks for suggesting Buffer. where i can find examples for working with Buffer?